# Segmentation fault (core dumped). 2D array with changing entries

Tags: c

I am working on a program which will find the shortest path from a robot to the exit. The robot will move vertically and horizontally on a 2d array. There will be 10 blocks impeding the movement of the robot. The exit will always be located at 0x7 and the position of the robots and the blocks are created randomly.

The approach that I am taking for finding the shortest path is by finding the position of the robot and then putting 1 in each possible position right, left, up and down. Then finding the 1, and putting 2 right, left, up and down. Then by finding the 2 and again, putting 3 right, right left, up and down. I will do that until I fill the matrix.

Then the shortest path will be from the robot to the exit following the numbers in increasing order. So, I think I have got most of the program done.

My problem is related to the function that will fill the matrix with 1,2,3,4.etc. I am getting the segmentation error, and I am assuming, after having done some research, that the error is because I am using memory that I don't have access to. If this is the case, I think the problem is my function for filling the matrix. Can you please help me discover what is wrong with my function? I am including what I have written so far for my program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
  int A[8][8],num=0;
  char B[8][8];
  char C[64];
  char D[64];

  intmatrix(A);
  charmatrix(B);
  matrixini(B,A);

  while(num<64) {
    matrix_find_fill(A,num);
    num++;
  }

  printmatrix(B,A);

  return 0;
}


int printmatrix(char B[8][8], int A[8][8]) {
  int i, j;
  for(i=0;i<8;i++) {
    for(j=0;j<8;j++) {
      printf("%c ",B[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
  }
  for(i=0;i<8;i++) {
    for(j=0;j<8;j++) {
      printf("%i ",A[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
  }
  return 0;
}

int charmatrix(char B[8][8]) {
  int i,j;
  for(i=0;i<8;i++) {
    for(j=0;j<8;j++) {
      B[i][j]=' ';
    }
  }
  return 0;
}

int intmatrix(int A[8][8]) {
  int i,j;
  for(i=0;i<8;i++) {
    for(j=0;j<8;j++) {
      A[i][j]=-1;
    }
  }
  return 0;
}

int matrixini(char B[8][8], int A[8][8]) {
  int r,c,a,b,n=0;
  srand((unsigned int)time(NULL) );
  a=rand()%9;
  b=rand()%9;
  B[a][b]='R';
  A[a][b]=0;
  B[0][7]='E';
  A[0][7]=99;
  do{
    r=rand()%8;
    c=rand()%8;
    if (B[r][c]==' ') {
      B[r][c]='#';
      A[r][c]=-2;
      n++;
    }
  } while(n<10);
  if ((B[0][6]=='#') && (B[1][7]=='#')) {
    printf("The Robot wont be able to exit.Game over!\n");
    exit(0);
  }
  return 0;
}

int matrix_find_fill(int A[8][8],int num) {
  int i,j;
  for(i=0;i<8;i++) {
    for(j=0;j<8;j++) {
      if(A[i][j]==num) {
        if(i==0) {
          if((j>=0) && (j<=7)) {
            if(j==0) {
              if(A[i+1][j]==-1) {
                A[i+1][j]=num+1;
              }
              if(A[i][j+1]==-1) {
                A[i][j+1]=num+1;
              }
            }
            if((j>0) && (j<7)) {
              if(A[i][j-1]==-1) {
                A[i][j-1]=num+1;
              }
              if(A[i][j+1]==-1) {
                A[i][j+1]=num+1;
              }
              if(A[i-1][j]==-1) {
                A[i-1][j]=num+1;
              }
            }
            if(j==7) {
              if(A[i+1][j]==-1) {
                A[i+1][j]=num+1;
              }
              if(A[i][j-1]==-1) {
                A[i][j-1]=num+1;
              }
            }
          }
          if((j<7) && (A[i][j+1]==-1)) {
            A[i][j+1]=num+1;
          }
        }
        if((i>0) && (i<7)) {
          if((j>=0) && (j<=7)) {
            if(j==0) {
              if(A[i+1][j]==-1) {
                A[i+1][j]=num+1;
              }
              if(A[i][j+1]==-1) {
                A[i][j+1]=num+1;
              }
              if(A[i-1][j]==-1) {
                A[i-1][j]=num+1;
              }
            }
            if((j>0) && (j<7)) {
              if(A[i][j-1]==-1) {
                A[i][j-1]=num+1;
              }
              if(A[i][j+1]==-1) {
                A[i][j+1]=num+1;
              }
              if(A[i-1][j]==-1) {
                A[i-1][j]=num+1;
              }
              if(A[i+1][j]==-1) {
                A[i+1][j]=num+1;
              }
            }
            if(j==7) {
              if(A[i+1][j]==-1) {
                A[i+1][j]=num+1;
              }
              if(A[i][j-1]==-1) {
                A[i][j-1]=num+1;
              }
              if(A[i-1][j]==-1) {
                A[i-1][j]=num+1;
              }
            }
          }
          if((j<7) && (A[i][j+1]==-1)) {
            A[i][j+1]=num+1;
          }
        }
        if(i==7) {
          if((j>=0) && (j<=7)) {
            if(j==0) {
              if(A[i-1][j]==-1) {
                A[i-1][j]=num+1;
              }
              if(A[i][j+1]==-1) {
                A[i][j+1]=num+1;
              }
            }
            if((j>0) && (j<7)) {
              if(A[i][j-1]==-1) {
                A[i][j-1]=num+1;
              }
              if(A[i][j+1]==-1) {
                A[i][j+1]=num+1;
              }
              if(A[i-1][j]==-1) {
                A[i-1][j]=num+1;
              }
            }
            if(j==7) {
              if(A[i-1][j]==-1) {
                A[i-1][j]=num+1;
              }
              if(A[i][j-1]==-1) {
                A[i][j-1]=num+1;
              }
            }
          }
          if((j<7) && (A[i][j+1]==-1)) {
            A[i][j+1]=num+1;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: when filling the matrix values, as part of finding the shortest path to the exit, a check must be made for each direction from the current direction, to avoid writing outside the matrix.  I.E. the function matrix_find_fill() needs to be re-designed.

Answer (score 1):

`a = rand() % 9` in `matrixini()` might come out to 8, which is out of bounds. Same with `b = rand() % 9`.

You probably want to change these to `a = rand() % 8` and `b = rand() % 8`.

Considering the length and trickiness of your code, you should probably restructure the `matrix_find_fill()` function into a simpler format.

Here's an idea of another way to do it:

```
int di[] = {0, 0, 1, -1};
int dj[] = {-1, 1, 0, 0};

int matrix_find_fill(int A[8][8], int num) {
  int i, j, k, ni, nj;
  for(i = 0; i < 8; i++) for(j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
    if(A[i][j] == num) {
      for(k = 0; k < 4; k++) {
        ni = i + di[k];
        nj = j + dj[k];
        if(ni >= 0 && nj >= 0 && ni < 8 && nj < 8 && A[ni][nj] == -1) {
          A[ni][nj] = num + 1;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Explanation:

For each position `(i, j)` that satisfies `A[i][j] = num`, we use `di` and `dj` to calculate the possible adjacent cells from `(i, j)`. Essentially, `ni` and `nj` cover all of these cases: `(i + 1, j), (i - 1, j), (i, j + 1), (i, j - 1)`.

Then, the if statement checks whether `ni` and `nj` are both in-bounds. We update `A[ni][nj]` to be `num + 1` if it is currently `-1`.

However, you should note that there are efficient shortest path algorithms that you should leverage, some of which are:

- [Breadth-first search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search)
- [Dijkstra's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra's_algorithm)

Also, I hope you didn't start testing the code after you wrote the entire program -- this almost always causes painful bugs.

Comment: I was testing the code and writing, but the part of filling the numbers has me so confused that I have changed the program several times. Thanks for the help though.

Comment: Does the if statement not take care of that? By using the if statement, I am saying that that can be done in just certain circumstances. Right? Thanks

Comment: Can you explain me your idea? I do not understand the code.

Comment: I've added an explanation in the answer and improved the code. Is there anything specific that you don't understand?

Comment: Got everything. Thanks :-)